# JQuery slider arrows

Tags: jquery, image, flexslider

I have a site on shopify and I would like to make the slider arrows fade in when you hover over it and fade out when the mouse leaves. Right now the arrows just abruptly appear. I have shopify's js file with the slider but I'm not sure where to edit the code. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: you need to check classes on arrows and add styles for them in your css file.

Answer (score 0):

You must add styles for arrows in your css file.

Example - https://jsfiddle.net/jc0otowt/2/

Code:

```
/* FlexSlider Fade In/Out Arrows*/
div.flexslider .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {
  left: 10px;
}

div.flexslider:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {
  left: 10px;
}

div.flexslider .flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
  right: 10px;
}

div.flexslider:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
  right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the div which hold the arrow and get the class, go to stylesheet.css and style this class with `opacity` 0 and `transition: all 1s ease`(or any timing function). then make it visible when mouse enter by adding `:hover` pseudo to the class and opacity 1.

the result would be like this :

```
.divClass {
  opacity:0;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.divClass:hover {
  opacity:1;
}
```

Or you can use JQ `fadeToggle` on `mouseover` `mouseout` events.